# Message "dfu-util: unable to read DFU status"

Tags: u-boot, lpc, dfu

DFU does not seem to work on a development board (Hitex LPC1850 or Keil MCB1800), but the manual states that it should work.

I could not find the same problem on the Internet, so I posted my problem here.
(I manually compiled dfu-util 0.7, but the lpcXpresso bundled binary gives a similar result.)

```
cd ~/u-boot
sudo ../dfu-util/src/dfu-util -R -D u-boot-dfu.bin  boot/u-boot/u-boot-dfu.bin  dfu-util 0.7
```

Output:

```
Copyright 2005-2008 Weston Schmidt, Harald Welte and OpenMoko Inc. Copyright 2010-2012 Tormod Volden and Stefan Schmidt This program is Free Software and has ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY Please report bugs to dfu-util@lists.gnumonks.org

Opening DFU capable USB device...
ID 1fc9:000c Run-time device DFU version 0100
Claiming USB DFU Runtime Interface...
Determining device status: state = dfuIDLE, status = 0
dfu-util: WARNING: Runtime device already in DFU state ?!?
Claiming USB DFU Interface...
Setting Alternate Setting #0 ...
Determining device status: state = dfuIDLE, status = 0
dfuIDLE, continuing
DFU mode device DFU version 0100
Device returned transfer size 2048
Copying data from PC to DFU device
Download    [=========================] 100%
90640 bytes Download done.
dfu-util: unable to read DFU status
```

The problem is, that I am not sure if [U-Boot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Das_U-Boot) has been executed. Reset (-R) should do that, but it tells me that it is 'unable to read dfu status'.

Am I missing something here? What might be the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already used `dfu-util` and this message has always been displayed, but it doesn't affect the Reset. Once you execute

```
dfu-util -R -D u-boot-dfu.bin
```

you should get a U-Boot console through the serial port (ttyS0... or *ttyUSB0* if you are using a serial-to-USB dongle...) using [Minicom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minicom) or a similar tool.

I ported U-Boot on the Hitex board in [SPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface) flash memory and using USB to get the console during an internship, so maybe I can help you further.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the message "dfu-util: unable to read DFU status" is normal.

The problem was that my bootloader was not working, because it was for a similar board with more internal SRAM. I just had to port my bootloader first, and the console is now working.